# Formatting JSON in post

Tags: javascript, json

I need to send the `id` and `quantity` as an integer. I define it as an integer, but for some reason when I try and post it, it posts the `id` as a string.

I'm missing something easy here, just no idea what.. How can I send both `id` and `quantity` as an integer? My code is below:

```
  var id = parseInt(identifier, 20);
  var quantity = parseInt(amount, 10);
  var updates = {};
  updates[id] = quantity;
  $.post('/cart/update.js', {updates: {updates}});
```

The JSON in the post should look like this:

```
$.post('/cart/update.js', {updates: {40076307207: 1}});
```

Thanks

Comment: As i see the updates is an object but right after it you use it as an array.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`$.post` doesn't send JSON, it uses `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` format. This format does not distinguish data types, everything is sent as a string. If a parameter is supposed to be an integer, you need to convert it in the server code.

Also, in JSON, object keys are always strings.

In order to get the structure you want, it should be:

```
$.post('/cart/update.js', {updates: updates});
```

You're adding an extra level of nesting, because `{updates}` is the ES6 shorthand for `{updates: updates}`, so you're sending `{updates: {updates: updates}}`.